# Finding default network printer IP Address

Tags: powershell

I need to find the IP address of my default networked printer using a powershell script.

I have the following so far, it gives me the printer name but I need the IP Address as well?

```
    #Declare Global Variables
Set-Variable -Name DefaultPrinter -Scope Global -Force

cls
If ((Test-Path $env:APPDATA"\DefaultPrinter.txt") -eq $true) {
    Remove-Item -Path $env:APPDATA"\DefaultPrinter.txt" -Force
}
$ComputerName = "localhost"

$DefaultPrinter = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_printer -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter "Default='true'"
$DefaultPrinterPortIP = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter "name='$($DefaultPrinter.PortName)'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostAddress

Write-Host "Default Printer: " -NoNewline
If ($DefaultPrinter.Name && $DefaultPrinterPortIP.HostAddress -ne $null) {
    $DefaultPrinter.Name | Out-File -FilePath $env:APPDATA"\DefaultPrinter.txt" -Force -Encoding "ASCII"
    Write-Host $DefaultPrinter.Name
} else {
    $DefaultPrinter = "No Default Printer"
    $DefaultPrinter | Out-File -FilePath $env:APPDATA"\DefaultPrinter.txt" -Force -Encoding "ASCII"
    Write-Host $DefaultPrinter

#Cleanup Global Variables
Remove-Variable -Name DefaultPrinter -Scope Global -Force
```

It is not giving me the ip address of the pritner and keeps returning nothing.

Comment: That's because `Win32_Printer` does not contain IP Address information : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Do you know how i would get the ip address information please?

Comment: Do you know the printer's hostname?  If so, you can utilize DNS to lookup the information you need by using the `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName()` .net method

Answer (score 0):

This in fact does work and returns an ip address, it was due to a limitation on my computer, tested on the network we actually want to use it on and it works fine.

Thanks you to all who contributed along the way.

Thanks,